# Matplotlib ColorbarBase: delete color separators

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I'd like to delete the back line-separators (dividers?) in the drawn colormap, using ColorbarBase:

```
cm    = get_cmap('RdBu')
Ncol  = 501
cccol = cm(1.*arange(Ncol)/Ncol)
cax     = fig.add_axes([0.15,0.15,0.05,0.4])
fig.add_axes([0.5,0.15,0.3,0.03])
norm    = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=valmin, vmax=valmax)
cb1     = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(cax, cmap=cm, norm=norm, orientation='vertical')
```

It always gives me too many black lines in between.. is there a way to eliminate them? I already tried stuff like:

```
del cb1.lines
del cb1.dividers
```

or

```
cb1.lines.remove()
cb1.lines = []
```

as seen in the ColorbarBase methods in http://fossies.org/dox/matplotlib-1.2.0/matplotlib_2colorbar_8py_source.html#l00281.

[image: colorbar with too many black lines]

Comment: .. or is it caused by the PNG output file format?
    
    plt.savefig('xxx.png')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it WAS indeed the matplotlib backend!

```
mpl.use('WXAgg')
```

solved it!

Answer (score 2):

That works for me, without any lines.  I see two obvious possibilities:

1) You have a buggy version.  If I do `matplotlib.__version__` at the python prompt, I see `1.2.0`.  I'm using OS X 10.6.8 with python 2.7.3, and everything installed from macports.  How about you?

2) It's something in the code you haven't shown us.  With questions like this, you should always show a minimal working example.  (Which can sometimes help you to figure out your problem before you even ask it.)  For example, I can start `ipython --pylab`, and the following works:

```
fig    = figure()
valmin =-1.0
valmax =1.0
cm     = get_cmap('RdBu')
Ncol   = 501
cccol  = cm(1.*arange(Ncol)/Ncol)
cax    = fig.add_axes([0.15,0.15,0.05,0.4])
norm   = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=valmin, vmax=valmax)
cb1    = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(cax, cmap=cm, norm=norm, orientation='vertical')
draw()
savefig('/tmp/bla.png')
```

Both the GUI that pops up and the PNG that gets saved show the following:

[image: Colorbar]

Does that work for you?  Have you done something significantly different in the rest of your code?

Comment: Alright, thanks!

I tried on my Ubuntu (12.04) with matplotlib 1.2.1 .. but on my OSX, it also works like a charme! ... I'm confused. As often.

Comment: aha... when I let it run in ipython, it works. But if i let it run as a script from the terminal with "python file.py" it creates the black lines..

Is it maybe a different backend, then?